# Visual Studio: Who is requiring a particular DLL?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I am using the Modules panel in Visual Studio to see which DLLs are being loaded.  How can I find out which executable/project/etc is requiring one of the specific DLLs?  I'm confused why the DLL is appearing in the Modules panel, and I'd like to figure out who is requiring it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening the .exe file of your program with [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) (open source) then navigate through the dependencies.

[image]

Image obtained from a question at askubuntu:
[Decompile .dll files without .net reflector](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772652/decompile-dll-files-without-net-reflector)